# How to add column in SELECT statement dynamically in tSQL based on condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I am creating a `tSql` with `parameters` and based on some condition I want to add column in SELECT statement and I am not sure how to do it.

My Logic:

```
var keywordClause = keyword.IsNotEmpty()
                    ? "[Name] like '%" + keyword + "%'"
                    : "1 = 1";
// keywordClause  = "[Name] like '%Test%'"

var orderBy = sortParameters.ToOrderBy();
// orderBy =  "Name ASC"

var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@Keyword", keywordClause),
    new SqlParameter("@OrderBy", orderBy)
};

var sql = string.Format(@"SELECT Id,
                                 Name,
                                 CreateDateTime Created
                          FROM CallCenter WITH (NOLOCK)
                          WHERE(IsDeleted = 0)
                          AND @Keyword 
                          ORDER BY @OrderBy");

return _PageList(ctx => ctx.CallCenterSummaries.SqlQuery(sql, parameters.ToArray())
                .AsQueryable()
                .Select(d => d.TrimSpaces()), page, pageSize);
```

Based on my logic, I am expecting this query:

```
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       CreateDateTime Created
FROM CallCenter WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE(IsDeleted = 0)
AND [Name] like '%Test%'
ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

Here I am getting `"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'."` exception and I believe it is taking `Name` as a string. How can I get desired results?

Comment: You need to alter the `sql` to include `[Name] like @Keyword"` and then pass `@Keyword` as a parameter.

Comment: You likely also want to escape the `keyword` value as well -         `public static string SqlLikeEscape(this string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
            return Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<ch>%|_|\[)", @"[${ch}]");
        }`

Comment: if you are using EF, why are you building SQL by hand? There is an easy way to do what you need with LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `SqlParameter` as an entire clause - it needs to be right hand side of the clause. For your scenario - the below should work.

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@Keyword", keyword.IsNotEmpty() ? keyword : "%")
};

var sql = string.Format($@"SELECT Id,
                                 Name,
                                 CreateDateTime Created
                          FROM CallCenter WITH (NOLOCK)
                          WHERE(IsDeleted = 0)
                          AND [Name] like @Keyword 
                          ORDER BY {orderBy}");
```

**EDIT:**
I've edited my code sample to use order by as a value in the interpolated string rather than as a `SqlParameter`, however, this does open you up to a Sql injection if the value of the `orderBy` is influenced by user's inputs.

Alternatively, I would recommend not using `ORDER BY` clause at all in your query and sorting results in memory before passing them back for display.

Comment: This gives me `The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.` error.

Comment: @CSharper you are right and I've edited my answer - you can't use the `ORDER BY` clause and a `SqlParameter` to control the value of the ordering field. If my answer doesn't meet your needs, check out this post which is pretty much asking how to solve your current problem with `ORDER BY` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442325/using-sqlparameter-to-create-order-by-clause

Comment: @ VidmantasBlazevicius That's what I found too. When I use ORDER BY with column name using CASE, I receives another error which is `the sqlparameter is already contained by another sqlparametercollection` so looking into that. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @CSharper have you considered ordering the results in memory? You don't have to do it in Sql, you could order results just before you return them.